# Deployment to Azure using Jenkins and github

Tags: azure, deployment, jenkins, amazon-cloudformation

I need to deploy code from github to Azure. i have configured jobs to perform test on the script and based on the result i want to deploy those script in Azure.

I need help on what jenkins plugin to us for deployment in Azure. if Plugin is not available do we have any other way to do a deployment from jenkins to Azure.

Any Links or Blogs will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins and Azure may work together, absolutely - just a two days ago there was another announcement [about that](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/18/announcing-azure-partnership/). You may host it in Azure.
But it looks like you want to host Jenkins outside of Azure.
I would offer you to try out [Visual Studio Team Services](http://visualstudio.com) - its build part. You can define the build and add Jenkins as the part of that process. There is the [plugin for Jenkins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=jenkins&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance) here with a good documentation on how to set up that.

[Here is the tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/jenkins-and-vso-vs) on integrating Jenkins and VSTS. And you can set up the deployment to Azure from the same tab - see how to use [VSTS build functionality](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/continuous-integration-vs.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. here i have the code available in Github and have configured Job in jenkins(Hosted outside of Azure) to do a basic test. once test is successful i want to deploy that code in Azure infrastructure. (similar like how we use jenkins plugin for code deploy in AWS) do we have any plugin to do it in Azure.